# Debugging in Android Studio... off by a line?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-debug

Something has been bothering me for awhile, and I'm wondering if I'm misremembering how things work or if something is wrong with my IDE setup.

Say I have a method

```
    public void normalDebuggerBehavior(String x) {
(BP)    int y = 12;
        int z = 10;
    }
```

If I set a breakpoint on the first line of the method `(BP)`, and the debugger stops on that breakpoint, shouldn't I be able to see the value of the passed parameter x without needing to step to the next line (`int z = 10`) either by right-clicking -> evaluate expression or by adding it to the watchlist? I would think this would be in scope at this point.

If I'm not able to do this, and I'm supposed to be able, what would cause this?

Screenshot:
[image: variable not in scope]

Stepping to the *next line* brings `vendor` into scope. Yes, this is a "fresh" compile.

Comment: Yes it's ok. If i understood you correctly - the debugger indeed executes line of code after you skip it and not when it is marked.

Comment: @GilMaimon Just to make sure we are indeed on the same page :), take the screenshot above. I don't expect `mVendor` to have the value of `vendor` assigned until AFTER I step through. That I agree with. However, shouldn't `vendor` (passed as a parameter) be available to inspect when stopped on the first line of the method?

Comment: You may be ask question having todo with when stack becomes avail to debugger within scope of the method?

Comment: It's not ok. It's a known bug of Android Studio. No sense in trying to defend a buggy IDE. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=119564

Answer (score 3):

Debuggers run on bytecode and not on Java source code. The mapping between Java source and bytecode is not always one-to-one.

When you place a breakpoint on the first line of a method, it is placed on the method entry point in the bytecode. The bytecode that actually reads in the method parameters has not been executed yet. You can observe this by looking at the bytecode disassembly and noticing the `aload` instructions at the beginning of a method with parameters.

Comment: That's interesting. Is there an easy way to look at "bytecode disassembly" to see this `aload` instruction?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that, since you are not using the argument `x` (in your example) the compiler gets rid of it, thus the debugger cant "see" it.

I think its a similar thing in your picture. It might be that the compiler optimises some stuff and thus the debugger cant see some variables...

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your jacoco test coverage off for the debug build in your build.gradle file:

```
debug {
    ...
    testCoverageEnabled false
}
```

This completely fixed the issue for me.